# Does workspaces or appstream have to be used in conjunction with ec2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-workspaces

Currently, I use ec2 instances to store data and deploy software to client's computers, within each instance there is a related database and the software so that the client can access it on their computer. Could I use workspaces as a replacement for the ec2 instance or would it only be able to provide a virtual gateway/desktop and require an ec2 instance to store the related data. Each client needs to store their own database and version of the software so I'm assuming that data can't be stored in a workspace. From my understanding workspace is a vdi and ec2 is a vm, so ec2 can store data and function as a desktop whereas workspace would only be able to relay information from an existing desktop.

Answer (score 0):

If you move your client's software AND data from EC2 to Amazon WorkSpaces you won't need the EC2 instances. You can see WorkSpaces as a polished version of EC2 for remote access. The storage on WorkSpaces is persistent so your EC2 instances won't be of any use.

FYI there are other solutions out there that will let you add multiple users on a single WorkSpace so you can save on hosting costs. Each users will have their own desktop session but use the same set of installed applications inside the same VM.

Hope that helps!